# Solve $y'=-3x^2\cdot y^2e^{-\frac{1}{y}}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Solve the initial value problem $y'(x)=-3x^2\cdot y(x)^2e^{-\frac{1}{y(x)}}$ with $y(e^{1/3})=1$ and, for each solution $\varphi$, find the maximal interval such that $\varphi$ is defined and solves the differential equation.

---

I've tried to all the common methods like separation of the variable but they seem to fail pretty bad. What's more, the above ODE is not linear so that already leaves out a lot of approaches one could use in order to solve this, which is why I haven't found a solution so far (nor the corresponding maximal interval(s)).

**Edit:** As you can see from the answers below, separation of the variable does in fact work.

Comment: Why did separation of variables fail?

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for the comment, I simply forgot to take $e^{-1/y}$ to the LHS and now it works (I will update the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-3x^2y^2e^{-\frac1y}$$
$$\frac 1{y^2}e^\frac1ydy=-3x^2dx$$
When you integrate left had side, use $z=\frac 1y$.

Answer (score 1):

The exponential containing the dependent function is "gnarly", so let's make a change of dependent variable intended to directly simplify that piece of your equation.  Let $y(x) = -1/\ln(z(x))$ so that $y'(x) = \frac{z'(x)}{z(x) \ln^2 z(x)}$.  Then the equation to solve is
$$  \frac{z'(x)}{z(x) \ln^2 z(x)} = \frac{-3x^2}{
\ln^2 z(x)} z(x)  \text{.}  $$
Since the logarithms cancel, this falls to separation of variables, starting with
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2} = -3x^2 \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$

Once you solve for $z(x)$, don't forget to return to the original variables with $z(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-1/y(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=-3x^2\cdot y^2e^{-\frac{1}{y}}$$
$$\dfrac {y'e^{\frac{1}{y}}}{ y^2}=-3x^2$$
Since we have: $$\dfrac  {y'}{y^2} =-\left (\dfrac 1y \right)' =-\dfrac {d}{dx}\left (\dfrac 1y \right)$$
$$(e^{\frac{1}{y}})'=3x^2$$
$$d(e^{\frac{1}{y}})=3x^2dx$$
And integrate.